# Accessing backend specific functionality with Julia Plots

Tags: matplotlib, julia, plots.jl

`Plots` is simple and powerful but sometimes I would like to have a little bit more control over individual elements of the plot to fine-tune its appearance.

Is it possible to update the plot object of the backend directly?

E.g., for the default `pyplot` backend, I tried

```
using Plots
p = plot(sin)
p.o[:axes][1][:xaxis][:set_ticks_position]("top")
```

but the plot does not change. Calling `p.o[:show]()` afterwards does not help, either.

In other words: Is there a way to use the `PyPlot` interface for a plot that was initially created with `Plots`?

**Edit:**

The changes to the `PyPlot` object become visible (also in the gui) when saving the figure:

```
using Plots
using PyPlot
p = Plots.plot(sin, top_margin=1cm)
gui() # not needed when using the REPL
gca()[:xaxis][:set_ticks_position]("top")
PyPlot.savefig("test.png")
```

Here, I used `p.o[:axes][1] == gca()`. One has to set `top_margin=1cm` because the plot area is not adjusted automatically (for my actual fine-tuning, this doesn't matter).

This also works for subsequent updates as long as only the `PyPlot` interface is used. E.g., after the following commands, the plot will have a red right border in addition to labels at the top:

```
gca()[:spines]["right"][:set_color]("red")
PyPlot.savefig("test.png")
```

However, when a `Plots` command like `plot!(xlabel="foo")` is used, all previous changes made with `PyPlot` are overwritten (which is not suprising).

The remaining question is how to update the gui interactively without having to call `PyPlot.savefig` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

No - the plot is a Plots object, not a PyPlot object. In your specific example you can do `plot(sin, xmirror = true`).

Comment: But you can edit a Plots object directly, using Plots notation. In this case `p[1][:xaxis][:mirror] = true; display(p)` . `display()` is essential for any updates of the plot to show.

Comment: I understand that `p` is a `Plots` object, but it seems to wrap an at least partially functional `PyPlot` object in `p.o`, see my updated question for a workaround.  Of course, one should use the `Plots` interface if possible, like in this example, but sometimes I know only how to make a specific change in `PyPlot`. Therefore, I would appreciate a way to completely hand over control to `PyPlot` (when using the `pyplot` backend) after 90% of the plot is done in `Plots`.

Comment: Very impressive hacking :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same but didn't find a solution to update an existing plot. But here is a partial answer: you can query information from the PyPlot axes object

```
julia> Plots.plot(sin, 1:4)

julia> Plots.PyPlot.plt[:xlim]()
(1.0,4.0)

julia> Plots.plot(sin, 20:24)

julia> ax = Plots.PyPlot.plt[:xlim]()
(20.0,24.0)
```

and it gets updated.

Comment: Interesting. BTW you don't need Plots in front of PyPlot.

Comment: But I'd be very surprised if this can be used to do anything to edit the plot.

Comment: And I didn't manage to edit the plot. I looked through `Plots.jl` source code for a while and just couldn't figure out why `Plots` updates the plot correctly but why I couldn't sneak it. I guess my julia skills aren't good enough, I should have used the debugger to see what actually is called.